# Cocoa NSView subview blocking drag/drop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop, nsview

I have an NSView subclass which registers for drag files in init method like this:

```
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
```

The drag drop works perfectly fine, but if I add a subview to this view with the exact same frame, it doesn't work any more. My guess is that the subview is block the drag event to go to super view. Can can I avoid that? Thanks

Also, I know I am asking two questions, but I don't want to create a new topic just for this: When I am dragging, my cursor doesn't change to the "+" sign like with other drags, how can I do that?
Thanks again.

UPDATE:
Here's the how I have it set up in my IB:
[image]

The DrawView is the custom class I was talking about that registered for draggedtypes. And the Image view simply is a subview, I dragged an image from the media section...
If it helps, here's my relevant code for DragView:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pboard;
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    NSArray *list = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    if ([list count] == 1) {
        BOOL isDirectory = NO;
        NSString *fileName = [list objectAtIndex:0];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName
                                             isDirectory: &isDirectory];
        if (isDirectory) {
            NSLog(@"AHH YEA");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOO");
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the subview? I'm able to drag into a view with a subview created either through IB or programmatically.

Comment: I have the view set up in IB. I set it's class to the custom class I described above. Then in IB, I drag an image and put it inside that view (make it a subview). When I do that, the dragging stops working. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the original question providing more details. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at Steven's answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782636/nsview-subviews-interrupting-drag-operation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the second part of your question is this:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}
```

if you return `NSDragOperationCopy`, you get the mouse badge for a copy operation. (You can and should, of course, not just return `NSDragOperationCopy` unconditionally; check the objects on the pasteboard to see if you can accept them.)

I'm not sure what the answer to the first part of your question is, because I'm unable to recreate the subview blocking effect.

Okay, the answer is unfortunately that you can't. The image you dragged is contained in an `NSImageView`, and `NSImageView`s accept drag events themselves, so it's grabbing the drag event and not doing anything with it. If your subview was a custom class, you could either a) not implement drag and drop, in which case the drags *would* be passed through; b) implement drag and drop to accept drags for the subview. In this case, you're using a class over which you don't have any control. If all you want it to do is display an image, you should be able to make another `NSView` subclass that does nothing but draw the image in `drawRect:`

Comment: Thanks for the input, it worked perfectly. Main my question was the first question, that why I am not marking it as accepted, but I am thumbing it up. Thanks again.

Comment: With those details, I have the rest of your answer. Good luck, thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @Bavarious: It's certainly not passing them through; I can't say for sure what it's doing with them. I'd guess just returning `NSDragOperationNone`. If you have a similar situation to OP, with an image view slightly smaller than the drag-enabled superview, you can do a drag "around" the image view, but not when the mouse enters the image view's frame.

Comment: As mentioned above (and linked to the original [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782636/nsview-subviews-interrupting-drag-operation)) the answer is to unregister the NSImageView's dragged types using `[imageView unregisterDraggedTypes];`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, NSImageViews have their own drag and drop enabled by default (used for accepting images that are dragged onto the NSImageView). If you don't want to use this behavior and instead want to use the super view's drag and drop behavior, you'll want to unregister the dragging behavior in the NSImageView.

Objc:

```
[imageView unregisterDraggedTypes];
```

Swift:

```
imageView.unregisterDraggedTypes()
```

(in case anyone else stumbled across this question first and not the linked one in the comments)