# Drag and drop blocked by a QTMovieView

Tags: cocoa

I'm new to Cocoa and Objective-C but and this may be a very basic question.
My problem is that I have a NSWindow with a QTMovieView that should accept dragged files.
The delegate class of the window implements the NSDraggingDestination protocol and I have the required methods to accept the file as defined on the NSDraggingDestination.
It all works when I drag the file to the title bar but when I drag over the QTMovieView it no longer accepts the file.
The strange thing is that this was working before.
Can someone tell me what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few months ago.

[Forwarding drag & drop event to parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262514/forwarding-drag-drop-event-to-parent-view)

You have to unregister the QTMovieView so that it forwards the event to the parent view.
That should be it.

Best,

Flo